# Term for “pressure relief valve”

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

For a history paper, my argument is that the American Frontier acted as a sort of *pressure relief valve* for Colonial dissidents who did not agree with Puritan theology. What is a more appropriate word or term for *pressure relief valve*?

Comment: But what they call [The Great Migration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puritan_migration_to_New_England_(1620%E2%80%931640)) was *Puritans* heading for the new land because *they* weren't happy with their circumstances and treatment in England.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think the O.P. is referring to an exodus of folks from those original colonies to what we call the "Old West" or ["Wild West"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_west), beginning in the early 1800s.

Comment: @J.R.: oic. American history's not my strong suit!

Comment: No close votes needed I think. Frankly, I see a good question here, but fail to find the right answer to offer. Should come back if I find any luck.

Comment: BTW, there's nothing wrong with _pressure relief valve_. Some dictionaries (like [this one](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Pressure+relief+valve)) make explicit mention of the term's metaphorical usage.

Comment: Gaussian_blur, Would *escape route* work?

Comment: Voting to close because I have no idea what you mean by "more appropriate" term.  There's nothing obviously wrong with just saying "release valve" so without knowing what you find distasteful about it, it's hard to offer any alternatives.

Comment: perhaps `a way out`, or `an escape`?

Answer (score 1):

How about *diversion* (since the pressure was diverted by the Frontier) or *distraction*, or *respite* (if it was only a temporary relief)?

Answer (score 1):

You could say that the dissidents sought "[solace](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/solace)" from the Puritans in the American Frontier.

> sol·ace
>   n.
>   1. Comfort in sorrow, misfortune, or distress; consolation.
>   2. A source of comfort or consolation.

If these dissidents felt oppressed by religious dogma, solace works well.

To use a verb, you could say that westward expansion into the American Frontier "[alleviated](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/alleviate?s=t)" the pressure colonial dissidents felt in a largely puritanical society.

> al·le·vi·ate
>   verb (used with object) 1.
>   to make easier to endure; lessen; mitigate: to alleviate sorrow; to alleviate pain.

To be perfectly honest, though, I think a "pressure release valve" is a perfectly acceptable metaphor to explain Westward Expansion--it's not overly casual and requires no great leaps in logic.

Comment: The safe haven of the Wild West?

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic phrase in my experience is *safety valve*.